# Add slashes used in strings

Tags: php

I am new to php . Few days back I came up with Add Slashes . 
I need to know what it is  and How is it used in strings .

Could any one help me ? 
Thank you friends

Comment: Have you tried uhhhmmm... [the official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)?

Comment: Took me 2 seconds to find:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addslashes() function returns a string with backslashes in front of predefined characters.

The predefined characters  are:

single quote (')
double quote (")
backslash ()
NULL

In this example we will add backslashes to the predefined characters in a string:

```
<?php
$str = "Who's Kai Jim?";
echo $str . " This is not safe in a database query.<br />";
echo addslashes($str) . " This is safe in a database query.";
?>
```

The output of the code above will be:

Who's Kai Jim? This is not safe in a database query.
Who\'s Kai Jim? This is safe in a database query.

You can find a complete PHP documentation in http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp

Comment: Next time please do search or put in your efforts before asking !!Thank u

Comment: Don't direct people to w3school. Especially not on the topic of SQL injection prevention. BTW addslashes isn't the correct way to prevetn sql injection. prepared statements and bound paramaters is.

Comment: @jat Appreciate the help

Comment: @PeeHaa All I was trying to ask was the proper documentation on the web so that I can learn the basics of PHP .

Comment: For more information about prepared about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ): you can use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).